# java utf-8 encding problem

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, character-encoding

i am using an HTML parser called **HTMLCLEANER** to parse HTML page
the problem is that each page has a different encoding than the other.
my question

Can i change from any character encoding to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you get the HTML page from? If you get it from the servlet request, you can use getReader() on it and pass that to [`clean()`](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/HtmlCleaner.html#clean(java.io.Reader)). This will use the right encoding. If you get it from an upload, pass the input stream to `clean()`. If you get it by http client, you need to check the reponse header `Content-Type` using [`getResponseCharSet()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethodBase.html#getResponseCharSet()).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot seamlessly "convert" from encoding X to encoding Y without knowing encoding X beforehand. Just check the HTTP response header which encoding it is using (if you're obtaining those HTML pages by HTTP) and then use the appropriate encoding in your HTML parser tool.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i change from any character
>   encoding to UTF-8?

Yes, you can express any Unicode character in UTF-8 encoding.

There might be a problem when changing the encoding of HTML pages: if the page contains an "charset" Meta-Tag, for example,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

you have to update this tag so it corresponds to the actual encoding.

Comment: He's parsing a HTML page, not generating a HTML page. Besides, this line actually **instructs** the client side which encoding to use to parse the given HTML page (and that is *exactly* the information the OP doesn't know about beforehand and thus need to find out in the response headers!).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void arreglarString(String cadena) {
    for (int i = 161; i < 256; i++) {
        char car =  (char) i;
        cadena = cadena.replaceAll(car + "", "&#" + i); 
    }

    return cadena;
}
```